# Custom Crop Size in UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios

I've been struggling with this for awhile now, since there is little documentation on the subject. I have a `UIImagePickerController` in my iPhone application that I use to select an image to be applied as the background of a view later. This is easy enough to do. Unfortunately, if a user selects a large image from their camera roll it needs to be resized and cropped in order to look decent.

It's easy enough to toggle `picker.allowsEditing` to `YES` and get the image editor up, but the default crop dimensions are too small. I need to set it to the full dimensions of the iPhone screen (320 for the old models, 640 for the new). How do you do that? I've been Googling and looking at Apple's documentation, but I can't find anything. The best I found is a slightly buggy solution from 2009 (http://blog.stormyprods.com/2009/06/image-picker-sample.html) that *almost* works, but it shifts the image down about 20px. (Plus, it's a bit over-complicated.) Surely there's an elegant, simple solution that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

One year later - Hi, like you, i haven't found anything useful, so i created this Project 
- a custom size crop and zoom editing UIImagePicker Popover for the iPad.

You could easily change it for the iphone, hope that helps someone.
Here it is - https://github.com/yogev77/UIImagePickerWithEditor

Comment: Crop while taking the photo not after! The above github project is not a solution for the question posted above. If you set the image source to be camera, the editing crop box pops up after taking the photo not while taking the photo.

Comment: can't solve the memory issue. i want to shrink the memory usage of my 8M camera

Comment: @Gamma-Point you want to size and crop WHILE taking a photo? That is not what this question asks for

Answer (score 0):

May be this should work :

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image CovertToSize:(CGSize)size {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
      [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
      UIImage *destImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();    
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
      return destImage;
}
```