# How to remove square ratio cropping for images on IOS

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

I am using the IOS standard image cropping functionality (move and scale) to crop my image before submitting it to the server.

However, I realize that the cropping provided has a square ratio (see screenshot below)

[image]

Snippet of the code is as follows:

```
//set up image picker
self.imgPicker = [[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init]autorelease];
self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
self.imgPicker.delegate = self;

//Trigger get photo from library function
self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentModalViewController:self.imgPicker animated:YES];
```

How can allow 'move and scale' editing and at the same time allow the user to do cropping WITHOUT the square ratio restriction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change the UIImagePickerController crop frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/998706/how-to-change-the-uiimagepickercontroller-crop-frame)

Comment: You're right CodaFi, this question has been asked all over stackoverflow. This thread can also be useful, as a user suggests his framework : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740253/custom-crop-size-in-uiimagepickercontroller. Here is the framework : https://github.com/yogev77/UIImagePickerWithEditor. But I haven't used it, so I can't give any opinion about it.

Comment: There is your answer..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9041732/set-dimensions-for-uiimagepickercontroller-move-and-scale-cropbox

Answer (score 15):

I think you need change `self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = YES;` to `self.imgPicker.allowsEditing = NO;`

Answer (score 3):

This library can help you.

https://github.com/gekitz/GKImagePicker

It supports custom cropping and it's easy to integrate with the native picker if needed.

Comment: This project does not work with taking picture from the camera. It always goes to gallery.

Answer (score 0):

I think , this will serve your purpose . You can change the constraints as you want

https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/PEPhotoCropEditor?source=cc